# React Select label not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using the React Select Library and when I pick a label in the select field, the value shows instead of the label.  When I click the dropdown, the labels show, but when I select a label, the value shows instead of the label.

I'm building my field here:

```
payment_code: {
            label: "Payment Code", value: 'payment_code', choices: paymentCodes.map((payment_code) => {

                displayChoices.payment_code[payment_code['id']] = payment_code['name'];
                console.log(displayChoices.payment_code);
                return {
                    label: payment_code['name'], value: payment_code['id']
                }
            }), type: 'choice'
        },
```

The other fields work correctly but this one does not.  I'm not a  front end developer so I'm pretty stumped with this.  I'd add the JSX but like I said, it's working correctly for the other fields.

Comment: Can you add the JSX? And also what paymentCodes is? Hard to debug especially without at least some sample data.

Comment: Thanks but I actually figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but

```
return {
    label: payment_code['name'], value: payment_code['id']
}
```

should've been

```
return {
    label: payment_code['name'], value: payment_code['id'].toString()
}
```

For some reason, the value needs to be a string.

Comment: If you see console log with a warning message Failed prop type: Invalid prop `placeholder` of type `number` supplied to `SingleValue`, expected `string`.